# Telling lessphp that i have to check a folder not only a single file to refresh the output.css?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, less

I includet lessphp with this code:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/less/lessc.inc.php');
$less = new lessc;
$less->checkedCompile(__DIR__."/less/style.less", __DIR__."/css/style.css");
```

But because I include som other less files in the style.less I have to remove everytime after any change on any imported less file the output.css that I see the changes... anyone have any idea how I can tell the script that he have to check the whole folder "less" for any changes?

And please explain it easy for me.. my english is verry bad and I have no idea about php, maybe with a code example

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#compiling_automatically).

> There’s a problem though. checkedCompile is very basic, it only checks the input file’s modification time. It is unaware of any files from @import.
>
> For this reason we also have cachedCompile. It’s slightly more complex, but gives us the ability to check changes to all files including those imported. It takes one argument, either the name of the file we want to compile, or an existing cache object. Its return value is an updated cache object.

So it seems that `cachedCompile` is the method for you.

This is the code for your case:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/less/lessc.inc.php');

$inputFile  = __DIR__ . "/less/style.less";
$outputFile = __DIR__ . "/css/style.css";
$cacheFile  = $inputFile . ".cache";

if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($cacheFile));
} else {
    $cache = $inputFile;
}

$less = new lessc;
$newCache = $less->cachedCompile($cache);

if (!is_array($cache) || $newCache["updated"] > $cache["updated"]) {
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, serialize($newCache));
    file_put_contents($outputFile, $newCache['compiled']);
}
```

Comment: Bro... this is the awesomst support i ever get! Thank you so much for this ultra usefull post!